# Solution for preventing indexing of content types?

Tags: nodes, search

I have a custom content type that I simply want to not be indexed by the Drupal search engine.  Yes, I can hide it from the search results, but there are hundreds of thousands of these nodes and rebuilding the index takes days.  After much searching and trial/error, I came across [this solution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33717/dont-index-certain-content-types) from ChrisPliakus.

You can see my query below in the update_index hook, where I exclude MY_CONTENT_TYPE from the query. I've tested the query manually and it seems to show nodes other than the one I want to ignore, which I think is the goal there.

However, when I run drush cron --verbose, I still see those nodes getting indexed :(

---

```
/**
 * Implements hook_module_implements_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ('update_index' == $hook) {
    unset($implementations['node']);
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_update_index().
 *
 * @see node_update_index().
 */
function MYMODULE_update_index() {
  $limit = (int) variable_get('search_cron_limit', 100);

  $result = db_query_range("SELECT n.nid FROM {node} n LEFT JOIN {search_dataset} d ON d.type = 'node' AND d.sid = n.nid WHERE (d.sid IS NULL OR d.reindex <> 0) AND n.type != 'MY_CONTENT_TYPE' ORDER BY d.reindex ASC, n.nid ASC", 0, $limit, array(), array('target' => 'slave'));

  foreach ($result as $node) {
    _node_index_node($node);
  }
}
```

---

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: From what I'm reading, I also need to implement hook_search_info, though I'm lost a bit at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than coding a custom solution, I would use a supported module. The answer I believe will help you: [Restrict Drupal Search to few content types](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12011/restrict-drupal-search-to-few-content-types?answertab=votes#tab-top)

So for Drupal 7 you can use [Custom Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_search), [Search Config](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_config) or [Search API Exclude](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_exclude) if you are using Search API. For Drupal 8 you can use [Search Exclude](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_exclude).